# Почему body не скроллится влево, хотя дочерний элемент выходит за границу слева?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть элемент с классом `map-container`, с помощью скрипта я могу увеличивать или уменьшать его размеры с помощью `tranform: scale()`, когда элемент становится больше чем видимая часть экрана, появляется возможность скрола вниз и вправо, но элемент выходит за границу слева и нет возможности его проскролить. Как это решить?

```css
.map-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2414px;
  height: 1902px;
  background: url(../../img/map.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 30% 0%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  background-color: #1f222e;
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<body class="dragscroll">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="map-container"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Картинка не помещается слева, но возможности проскроллить налево нет
[image: Вид]

Comment: непонятно в чем проблема. Приложите демо.

Comment: Здравствуйте! А в чём проблема сделать так, чтобы `div` помещался в экран в максимальный размер через `max-width`? Webkit: 
`max-width: -webkit-available;`, для Firefox: `max-width: -moz-available;`, для Opera: `max-width: -o-available;`.

Comment: потому что минимальное значение скролла - 0. Он не может прокручиваться левее.

Comment: подробнее тут: [Why doesn't the scroll bar appear even if it protrudes to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132573/2881286)